# scale_color_brewer in ggplot2 assigns different order for categorical colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large DF with 1000 observations that I display two times in different colors.

I use scale_color_brewer to assign colors. ggplot2 assigns different colors to the categorical variables, i.e. the 2nd and 3rd variable are switched (blue and purple) in one of the graphs, as shown below.

[image]

I saw the other thread on the stable mapping of colors, and I am currently working on using this work around, but from my limited understanding I assumed that s_c_b always assigns the same colors, depending on the order provided by breaks = c(...).

Code for Top Graph:

```
    penaltyfactor_graph <-ggplot(p1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(VaR), y = as.numeric(Mean), colour=factor(Penalty_Factor))) +
  xlab("Portfolio VaR (in Mil $)")+
  ylab("Profit (in Mil $)")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = -50, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=0.8)+
  labs(colour = "Penalty
Factor")+
  scale_color_brewer(breaks=c("1","5","10","50","100"), palette = "Set1")
```

Code for Bottom Graph:

```
    p2 <- as.data.frame(verification_graph_data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggthemr("flat")
Noise_graph <- ggplot(p2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(VaR), y = as.numeric(Mean), colour=factor(Noise_Size))) +
  xlab("Portfolio VaR (in Mil $)")+
  ylab("Profit (in Mil $)")+
  labs(colour = "Noise  
Set")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = -50, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=0.8)+
  scale_color_brewer(breaks=c("0","1","2","5","10"), palette = "Set1")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `breaks` change the order of the legend but not the order the colors are assigned to the factor levels.  Set what you now have as the breaks as your `limits` to match the order of the colors with the order of the legend keys.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

So it's a bit hard to see what is happening here without a reproducible example (see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) but I think your Noise_Size and Penalty_Factor are characters. Therefore R is sorting them alphabetically not numerically (i.e. 0, 1, 10, 2, 5). You do not actually need to set `breaks` in scale_color_brewer if there are only these 5 values in each set. (If you aren't setting breaks it is more obvious what is happening.)

If you set them to factors in the data.frame before plotting, not within the plot and do not include the breaks (or you can, shouldn't actually make a difference) it should work. I.e.

```
 p1$Penalty_Factor <- as.factor(as.numeric(Penalty_p1$Penalty_Factor))
 penaltyfactor_graph <-ggplot(p1) +
   geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(VaR), y = as.numeric(Mean), colour=Penalty_Factor)) +
   xlab("Portfolio VaR (in Mil $)")+
   ylab("Profit (in Mil $)")+
   geom_vline(xintercept = -50, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=0.8)+
   labs(colour = "Penalty 
   Factor")+
   scale_color_brewer(breaks=c("1","5","10","50","100"), palette = "Set1")
```

On second thoughts will probably work if you put the `as.factor(as.numeric(Penalty_Factor))` in the ggplot call, it just has to have `as.numeric` or it is still sorting alphabetically.
If this doesn't work will need a reproducible example.

Comment: I think this works as well, but changing breaks to limits in the original brewer call works. Thank you